# Adding properties to pop ups in leaflet maps

Tags: leaflet, features, popup, html

I have a leaflet map which display pop-ups that give the name of a country when clicked. How can I add additional properties and have them all displayed, similar to this map http://lotrproject.com/map.

For example, how can I make my Iceland pop-up feature display the properties for "name" and "language", rather than just "name".

```
var countries = [
        {   type: "Feature",
            properties: { name: "Iceland", language: "Icelandic"},
            geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [2535,911] }
        },
        {   type: "Feature",
            properties: { name: "Ireland" },
            geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [1324, 1580] }
        },
        {   type: "Feature",
            properties: { name: "England" },
            geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [1498, 1662] }
        },
        {   type: "Feature",
            properties: { name: "France" },
            geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [1608, 1918] }
        },
        {   type: "Feature",
            properties: { name: "Italia" },
            geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [1923, 2093] }
        },
        {   type: "Feature",
            properties: { name: "Hispania" },
            geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [1374, 2148] }
        },
    ];

    var layerCountries = L.geoJson(countries, {
        // correctly map the geojson coordinates on the image
        coordsToLatLng: function(coords) {
            return rc.unproject(coords);
        },
        // add a popup content to the marker
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            if (feature.properties && feature.properties.name) {
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
            }
        },
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                    radius: 8,
                    fillColor: "#800080",
                    color: "#D107D1",
                    weight: 1,
                    opacity: 1,
                    fillOpacity: 0.8
                });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Leaflet popup you can just write plain HTML with anything you want. So instead of writing

```
layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
```

you could simply write

```
layer.bindPopup('<h1>'+feature.properties.name+'</h1><p>Language: '+feature.properties.language+'</p>');
```

If you would like to display automatically all properties as a table inside the popup window, you could build up your HTML dynamically, something like:

```
var popupContent = '<table>';
for (var p in feature.properties) {
    popupContent += '<tr><td>' + p + '</td><td>'+ feature.properties[p] + '</td></tr>';
}
popupContent += '</table>';
layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
```

Comment: First response works well! 

I'm attempting to use the dyanmic table within my code but I'm having trouble. Each time I try to implement it, my code breaks. Could you post the dynamic example showing how it would appear in the body of code I posted above?

Comment: @user3200293 I have indeed spotted a small error, it should be `feature.properties[p]` and not `feature.properties[k]`. I have edited my answer accordingly. I have made a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/chrikais/nbch0004/) based on your code (sorry, I did change the coordinates to some lat/long values so all points are now in Tchad, but you will get the idea).

Answer (score 0):

[bindPopup](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-bindpopup) takes html as an argument, so you can format it with as many properties as you want, using text, JavaScript variables and html together:

```
layer.bindPopup('Name: ' + feature.properties.name + '<br>' + 'Language: ' + feature.properties.language);
```

[This example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html) from the Leaflet docs may help:

```
L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.");
```

bindPopup works the same for markers and geojson layers